# Excevp into array to be used later

Tags: c

I am using execvp to find certain files. This is the code I am using:

```
char *argv1[] = {"find", "-name", "*.jpg", NULL};
execvp("find",argv1);
```

I was wondering is there a way to store/hold the results from the execvp into an array for later user? 
Also is there a way I can get only the desired file instead of the whole path?

This is my readdir() functoin.

```
static void list_dir (const char * dir_name)
{
    char *ArrayFiles[100];
    DIR * d;
    /* Open the directory specified by "dir_name". */
    int i = 0;
    d = opendir (dir_name);

    /* Check it was opened. */
if (!d) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
             dir_name, strerror (errno));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (1) {
    struct dirent * entry;
    const char * d_name;

    /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
    entry = readdir (d);
    if (! entry) {
        /* There are no more entries in this directory, so break
           out of the while loop. */
        break;
    }

   d_name = entry->d_name;
   if ((strstr(d_name, ".jpg")) || (strstr(d_name, ".JPG"))){
/* skip printing directories */
    if (! (entry->d_type & DT_DIR)) {
    char *filename = entry->d_name;
    printf ("%s\n", d_name); 
}
```

}

```
     if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {


            /* skip the root directories ("." and "..")*/
            if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {

                int path_length;
                char path[PATH_MAX];

                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,
                                        "%s/%s", dir_name, d_name);
                if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
                list_dir (path);
            }
        }

}

    /* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
    if (closedir (d)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `readdir()` and check for each entry?

Comment: iharob: I used readdir() to read directories and sub-directories for the desired files but putting into an array was complex for me mostly because of the recursion method I used to read sub-directories. I was just wondering if this is something that can be done.

Comment: Anything can be done, it's just a matter of finding the way to do it, can you post your `readdir()` code?

Comment: So you want the `listdir()` function to return an array with all the files that match? and why should you do this in c?

Comment: I have to use the files returned by the function for a bigger project but I somehow need to store this into an array in order to use them. I just can't seem a way to pass a directory in my main program and when the desired files are returned, store them into array for some other use.

Comment: If successful, [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) replaces the current process with the one it executes; there is no return. Maybe use [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)
to read the output of `find` into your current process. Or complete your directory search code, or use POSIX's [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) function. Maybe you should check the [`fnmatch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html) function too.